# Can't read QStringList from QML/JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml

I have a QML class that has a function in it with a QStringList as a parameter.  I'm able to access other items in the C++ model from QML just fine.

In my QML:

```
function recentFiles(recentFilesList)
{
    //This writes "0" for some reason, although it should be "3"
    console.log(recentFilesList.length)

    //Causes error: "Unable to assign [undefined] to QString"
    return recentFilesList[0]
}

...

Text {
    text: recentFiles(rootObject.myModel.recentFiles)
}
```

In my source file:

```
QStringList someModel::recentFiles() const
{
    QStringList recentFiles;

    recentFiles << "A" << "B" << "C";

    return recentFiles;
}
```

In my header file:

```
Q_INVOKABLE QStringList recentFiles() const;
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to get my `QStringList` to work on a QML `ListView` object where it will display like this:

1. A
2. B
3. C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is not a method call on `myModel`, you're passing `recentFiles` whatever passes for an invokable method wrapper in QML:

```
Text {
    text: recentFiles(rootObject.myModel.recentFiles)
}
```

You want to call the `recentFiles` method:

```
Text {
    //                                              vv !
    text: recentFiles(rootObject.myModel.recentFiles())
}
```

Alas, if your string list is mutable and can change while the UI is displayed, you should simply use a `QStringListModel`.

Comment: Doh!  I wish it would have thrown a compilation-like error...thank you!

Comment: @user1595510 It's still valid code, there's no error, it just doesn't mean what you think it means :) You can, of course, type check the arguments, but that's only of benefit if you do it everywhere.